# Unit test case for mat-menu with jest and @testing-library/angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, jestjs, angular-testing-library

I have a Component that uses `mat-menu` from Angular Material UI. When I call `fireEvent.click()`, I get an error: `TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find role="menu"` in console.

This is my test case:

```
test('it should open pages menu on button click', async () => {
  
  let component = await render(PaginationComponent, {
    imports:[MaterialModule]
  });
  let buttonCLick = fireEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('openChangePageSizeMenu'));
  expect(buttonCLick).toBeTruthy();

  await screen.findByRole('menu');

});
```

I am not able to point out where I am going wrong. I also read MatMenuHarness documentation [from here](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api#MatMenuHarness).

I am using **@testing-library/angular** and **jest**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some digging, the solution that I found is to add hidden: true. After adding this, the test case looks like this:

```
test('it should open pages menu on button click', async () => {
  
  let component = await render(PaginationComponent, {
    imports:[MaterialModule]
  });
  let buttonCLick = fireEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('openChangePageSizeMenu'));
  expect(buttonCLick).toBeTruthy();

  await screen.findByRole('menu', {hidden:true});

});
```

NOTE: this works for mat-dialog as well.